# What is the difference between :foo, ::foo, ::bar/foo, and :bar/foo in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

I came across those keywords: `:foo, ::foo, ::bar/foo, and :bar/foo`

Could you explain differences with examples?

Comment: Namespaced keywords are explained well in multiple places that would be found by searching. See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keyword and https://kotka.de/blog/2010/05/Did_you_know_III.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`:foo` is a non-fully-qualified keyword.  It has no namespace associated with it.

```lisp
(name :foo)            ; => "foo"
(namespace :foo)       ; => nil
```

`:bar/foo` is a namespace-qualified keyword.  The namespace is `bar`, and the name of the keyword is `foo`

```lisp
(name :bar/foo)        ; => "foo"
(namespace :bar/foo)   ; => "bar"
```

`::foo` will associate the current namespace with the keyword, making it fully qualified.  Assuming the current namespace is "user":

```lisp
*ns*                   ; => #namespace[user]
(name ::foo)           ; => "foo"
(namespace ::foo)      ; => "user"
::foo                  ; => :user/foo
```

`::bar/foo` will attempt to expand any aliases to make it fully qualified:

```lisp
(create-ns 'my.namespace)       ; => #namespace[my.namespace]
(alias 'bar 'my.namespace)      ; => nil
(name ::bar/foo)                ; => "foo"
(namespace ::bar/foo)           ; => "my.namespace"
::bar/foo                       ; => :my.namespace/foo
```

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.deepbluelambda.org/programming/clojure/know-your-keywords) explains it well.

TL;DR:

- `:foo` is a keyword without a namespace, i.e. an unqualified keyword.
- `:foo/bar` is a qualified keyword with an explicit namespace `foo`.
- `::foo` is an automatically qualified keyword. If this keyword occurs within a namespace `bar`, it is evaluated to `:bar/foo`.
- The namespace of `::bar/foo` is the same as `:baz/foo` if you require the namespace `bar :as baz`.

In code:

```
boot.user=> (ns foo)
nil
foo=> (ns bar (:require [foo :as f]))
nil
bar=> (def examples [:foo ::foo ::f/foo :bar/foo])
#'bar/examples
bar=> examples
[:foo :bar/foo :foo/foo :bar/foo]
bar=> (use 'clojure.pprint)
nil
bar=> (print-table (map (fn [example] 
                          {:key example :namespace (namespace example)
                           :name (name example)}) 
                     examples))

|     :key | :namespace | :name |
|----------+------------+-------|
|     :foo |            |   foo |
| :bar/foo |        bar |   foo |
| :foo/foo |        foo |   foo |
| :bar/foo |        bar |   foo |
```